# Recommended approach to insert many rows with Castle ActiveRecord and ignore any dupes

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, postgresql, castle-activerecord

I have a webmethod that inserts a bunch of recipes into a queue in the database (to store recipes the user is interested in cooking, similar to NetFlix's movie queue).  The user is able to check off a bunch of recipes at once and queue them.  I have code similar to this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void EnqueueRecipes(SecurityCredentials credentials, Guid[] recipeIds)
{
    DB.User user = new DB.User(credentials);

    using (new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Commit))
    {
       foreach (Guid rid in recipeIds)
       {
          DB.QueuedRecipe qr = new DB.QueuedRecipe(Guid.NewGuid(), user, new DB.Recipe(rid));
          qr.Create();
       }
    }
}
```

I have a unique constraint on UserId/RecipeId so a user can only enqueue a recipe once.  However, if they happen to select a recipe that's already in their queue I don't really want to bother the user with an error message, I just want to ignore that recipe.

The above code will throw a SQL exception if the unique constraint is violated.  What's the best approach to get around this, and simply ignore duplicate rows.  My current ideas are:

- 1) First load the user's entire queue from the database and check
  that list first.  If the recipe already exists, just `continue` in
  the for loop.  Pros: No unnecessary SQL inserts get sent to the
  database.  Cons: Slower, especially if the user has a big queue.
- 2) Don't use ActiveRecord and instead pass the entire recipeIds array
  into a SQL function.  This function will check if each row exists
  first.  Pros: Potentially fast, lets SQL handle all the dirty work. 
  Cons: Breaks ActiveRecord pattern and requires new DB code, which is
  often harder to maintain and costlier to implement.
- 3) CreateAndFlush after each loop.  Basically, don't run this entire
  loop in a single transaction.  Commit each row as it's added and
  catch SQL errors and ignore.  Pros: Low startup cost, and doesn't
  require new SQL backend code.  Cons: Potentially slower for inserting
  lots of rows into the database at once, though it's doubtful a user
  would ever submit over a dozen or so new recipes at once.

Are there any other little tricks with Castle or the NHibernate framework?  Also, my SQL backend is PostgreSQL 9.0.  Thanks!

**Update:**

I took a shot at the first approach and it seems to work pretty well.  It occured to me I don't have to load the entire queue, just the ones that appear in recipeIds.  I believe my `foreach()` loop is now O(n^2) depending on the efficiency of `List<Guid>::Contains()` but I think this is probably decent for the sizes I'll be working with.

```
//Check for dupes
DB.QueuedRecipe[] dbRecipes = DB.QueuedRecipe.FindAll(Expression.In("Recipe",
   (from r in recipeIds select new DB.Recipe(r)).ToArray()
));

List<Guid> existing = (from r in dbRecipes select r.Recipe.RecipeId).ToList();

using (new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Commit))
{
   foreach (Guid rid in recipeIds)
   {
      if (existing.Contains(rid))
         continue;

      DB.QueuedRecipe qr = new DB.QueuedRecipe(Guid.NewGuid(), user, new DB.Recipe(rid));
      qr.Create();
   }
}
```

Comment: List<T>.Contains is O(n), a HashSet<T> could be faster but in your case the amount of lookup`s is so small that you probably wont get a better overall performance because of the cost of creating the HashSet<T> in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a single SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_recipe
SELECT new_UserId, new_RecipeId
FROM   user_recipe
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   user_recipe
   WHERE  (UserId, RecipeId) = (new_UserId, new_RecipeId)
   );
```

The `SELECT` only returns the row if it doesn't already exist, so it will only be inserted in this case.

---

#### Solution for bulk inserts

If you have a long list of recipes to insert at once, you could:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE i(userId int, recipeid int) ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO i VALUES
(1,2), (2,4), (2,4), (2,7), (2,43), (23,113), (223,133);

INSERT INTO user_recipe
SELECT DISTINCT i.*  -- remove dupes from the insert candidates themselves
FROM   i
LEFT   JOIN user_recipe u USING (userid, recipeid)
WHERE  u.userid IS NULL;
```

---

#### Solution for inserting a handful at a time

Temporary table would be an overkill for just a few records, as Mike commented.

```sql
INSERT INTO user_recipe
SELECT i.* 
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT *     -- only if you need to remove possible dupes
    FROM (
       VALUES (1::int, 2::int)
          ,(2, 3)
          ,(2, 4)
          ,(2, 4)            -- dupe will be removed
          ,(2, 43)
          ,(23, 113)
          ,(223, 133)
       ) i(userid, recipeid)
    ) i
LEFT   JOIN user_recipe u USING (userid, recipeid)
WHERE  u.userid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yea that's definitely another option - Just drop down to using parameterized SQL..  It also seems a bit messy because I'd have to build a long string or SQL with potentially dozens of parameters (:recipe1, :recipe2, :recipe3, etc)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I added a bit on bulk INSERT to my answer.

Comment: Yea I doubt I'd ever create a temp table just for this..  But good info anyway for other readers.  Generating one big long SQL string might be a good way to go, though my solution above is probably not bad either as the user is very unlikely to select hundreds of recipes already in their queue.  I do generate raw SQL in my app for more advanced queries, but I consider it a last resort when using an ActiveRecord pattern.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I see you have a good solution already. But for science! (And it should be the best idea in pure SQL from me for you so far, too.)

Comment: Yea really all I wanted is to bounce some ideas around.  I appreciated your feedback for sure!